# Political Sci-Fi book from late 80's or earlier, humans getting involved in Alien tribal war

Tags: identification-request

I read an excellent political novel as a child (or was it a short story?), and I'm looking to find it again for my niece to read.

I may get some details wrong, but I remember there was a small group of people that somehow got stuck on a planet with two opposing tribes of aliens. Before they can come back to Earth they need to make peace between the tribes, and the "leader" human decides to partner with the weaker side in order to help them reach at least a stalemate that would allow peace. They use some technological inventions (involving making stuff out of ice somehow) to help the weaker tribe, and the scientist that worked on the technology is upset for not getting enough credit. Also, the leader uses the fact that the aliens don't like to be touched on the nose (or something similar) to get the leader of the other tribe to bite him, and then die (humans are toxic to them), so that the next in power who is more reasonable becomes leader and can reach an agreement.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like Poul Anderson's 'The Man who Counts', originally published as a novella 'The War of the Wing-Men'.
In it, his merchant-prince, Van Rijn, has crash-landed on a planet preoccupied by a war, and decides that his only hope of rescue is to shepherd 'his' side to victory.
Among other ploys, he gives a native the means to poison an uncooperative leader:

> "Inwardly she held a chill memory, how old Van Rijn had given her the coin but warned her against … what had he said? … heavy metal poisoning. "To you, iron, copper, tin is unknown stuffs. I am not a chemist, me; chemists I hire when chemicking is needful; but I think better I eat a shovelful arsenic than one of your cubs try teething on this piece money, by damn!"
>
> And she remembered sitting up in the dark, with a stone in her hand, grinding and grinding the coin, until there was seasoning for the unbendable admiral's dinner."

But this was a theme that interested Anderson: in 'Three Worlds to Conquer'(1964) humans intervene in a war on Jupiter (where most tools are made from ice) and in 'Fire Time' (1974) they intervene in a war on the planet Ishtar.